# Unsupported driver []

Tags: laravel-7, multi-database

I have Laravel project with multiple databases project is working fine on local serve but when I uploaded my project to server its showing **unsupported driver []** error Laravel version **7.0** php version **7.4**

after login I am trying to get data from third database on index page but its showing error

```
public function index()
{
    $srno = 1;
    $report = DB::connection('seocrm')->table('notifications')
            ->join('reports', 'reports.id', '=', 'notifications.report_id')
            ->orderBy('reporting_date','ASC')
            ->get();
    return view('index',compact('srno','report'));
}
```

here is my database.php file

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
    'salescrm' => [
        'driver' => env('DB_CONNECTION_SECOND'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECOND', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECOND', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND', ''),
        'unix_socket' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
    'seocrm' => [
        'driver' => env('DB_CONNECTION_THIRD'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_THIRD', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_THIRD', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_THIRD', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_THIRD', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_THIRD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

.env file

```
# for the first database
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=hrm
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=somepassword
# for the second database
DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql
DB_HOST_SECOND=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=salescrmdb
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=root
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=somepassword
# for the third database
DB_CONNECTION_third=mysql
DB_HOST_third=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_third=3306
DB_DATABASE_third=seocrmdb
DB_USERNAME_third=root
DB_PASSWORD_third=somepassword
```

please help to solve this error. Thanks in advance

Comment: If the server system is case sensitive like Linux, then `DB_CONNECTION_third` not the same as `DB_CONNECTION_THIRD` . Hope that help

Comment: yes it works. thank you rafah mnjd